# MemoryError on read serial SML and write it to postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, memory

I read from my electricity meter the values with a Raspberry pi and a USB IR meter head.
The whole thing runs in a Docker container and is a Python program.

The program reads the values from the meter checks the checksum and then writes to a loosely running Postgres database if the checksum is correct.

The script of wure was created with the help of this page:
https://www.stefan-weigert.de/php_loader/sml.php

Please bear with me a bit python and docker are still new to me.

The problem is that after the container runs for about 2 days it always comes to the following error.

Error Message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Thread._bootstrap of <Timer(Thread-40265317, initial 189230468)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self._set_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 909, in _set_tstate_lock
    _shutdown_locks.add(self._tstate_lock)
MemoryError
```

sml.py

```
##!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import logging
import serial
import binascii
from threading import Timer
import sys
from db import db

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

mystring = ""
crc16_x25_table = [
        0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329B, 0x4624, 0x57AD, 0x6536, 0x74BF,
        0x8C48, 0x9DC1, 0xAF5A, 0xBED3, 0xCA6C, 0xDBE5, 0xE97E, 0xF8F7,
        0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221A, 0x56A5, 0x472C, 0x75B7, 0x643E,
        0x9CC9, 0x8D40, 0xBFDB, 0xAE52, 0xDAED, 0xCB64, 0xF9FF, 0xE876,
        0x2102, 0x308B, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76AF, 0x4434, 0x55BD,
        0xAD4A, 0xBCC3, 0x8E58, 0x9FD1, 0xEB6E, 0xFAE7, 0xC87C, 0xD9F5,
        0x3183, 0x200A, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77A7, 0x662E, 0x54B5, 0x453C,
        0xBDCB, 0xAC42, 0x9ED9, 0x8F50, 0xFBEF, 0xEA66, 0xD8FD, 0xC974,
        0x4204, 0x538D, 0x6116, 0x709F, 0x0420, 0x15A9, 0x2732, 0x36BB,
        0xCE4C, 0xDFC5, 0xED5E, 0xFCD7, 0x8868, 0x99E1, 0xAB7A, 0xBAF3,
        0x5285, 0x430C, 0x7197, 0x601E, 0x14A1, 0x0528, 0x37B3, 0x263A,
        0xDECD, 0xCF44, 0xFDDF, 0xEC56, 0x98E9, 0x8960, 0xBBFB, 0xAA72,
        0x6306, 0x728F, 0x4014, 0x519D, 0x2522, 0x34AB, 0x0630, 0x17B9,
        0xEF4E, 0xFEC7, 0xCC5C, 0xDDD5, 0xA96A, 0xB8E3, 0x8A78, 0x9BF1,
        0x7387, 0x620E, 0x5095, 0x411C, 0x35A3, 0x242A, 0x16B1, 0x0738,
        0xFFCF, 0xEE46, 0xDCDD, 0xCD54, 0xB9EB, 0xA862, 0x9AF9, 0x8B70,
        0x8408, 0x9581, 0xA71A, 0xB693, 0xC22C, 0xD3A5, 0xE13E, 0xF0B7,
        0x0840, 0x19C9, 0x2B52, 0x3ADB, 0x4E64, 0x5FED, 0x6D76, 0x7CFF,
        0x9489, 0x8500, 0xB79B, 0xA612, 0xD2AD, 0xC324, 0xF1BF, 0xE036,
        0x18C1, 0x0948, 0x3BD3, 0x2A5A, 0x5EE5, 0x4F6C, 0x7DF7, 0x6C7E,
        0xA50A, 0xB483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xE32E, 0xF2A7, 0xC03C, 0xD1B5,
        0x2942, 0x38CB, 0x0A50, 0x1BD9, 0x6F66, 0x7EEF, 0x4C74, 0x5DFD,
        0xB58B, 0xA402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xF3AF, 0xE226, 0xD0BD, 0xC134,
        0x39C3, 0x284A, 0x1AD1, 0x0B58, 0x7FE7, 0x6E6E, 0x5CF5, 0x4D7C,
        0xC60C, 0xD785, 0xE51E, 0xF497, 0x8028, 0x91A1, 0xA33A, 0xB2B3,
        0x4A44, 0x5BCD, 0x6956, 0x78DF, 0x0C60, 0x1DE9, 0x2F72, 0x3EFB,
        0xD68D, 0xC704, 0xF59F, 0xE416, 0x90A9, 0x8120, 0xB3BB, 0xA232,
        0x5AC5, 0x4B4C, 0x79D7, 0x685E, 0x1CE1, 0x0D68, 0x3FF3, 0x2E7A,
        0xE70E, 0xF687, 0xC41C, 0xD595, 0xA12A, 0xB0A3, 0x8238, 0x93B1,
        0x6B46, 0x7ACF, 0x4854, 0x59DD, 0x2D62, 0x3CEB, 0x0E70, 0x1FF9,
        0xF78F, 0xE606, 0xD49D, 0xC514, 0xB1AB, 0xA022, 0x92B9, 0x8330,
        0x7BC7, 0x6A4E, 0x58D5, 0x495C, 0x3DE3, 0x2C6A, 0x1EF1, 0x0F78]
class Database:
        #init database
        _db = db()        

class Watchdog_timer:
        
        def __init__(self, timeout, userHandler=None):
                self.timeout = timeout
                self.handler = userHandler if userHandler is not None else self.defaultHandler
                self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)
                self.timer.start()

        def reset(self):
                self.timer.cancel()
                self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)
                self.timer.start()

        def stop(self):
                self.timer.cancel()

        def defaultHandler(self):
                raise self

def crc16_x25(Buffer):
        crcsum = 0xffff
        global crc16_x25_table
        for x in range(0, len(Buffer)):
              if (x % 2) == 0: 
                   byte = binascii.unhexlify(Buffer[x:x+2])
                   crcsum = crc16_x25_table[(ord(byte) ^ crcsum) & 0xff] ^ (crcsum >> 8 & 0xff)
        crcsum ^= 0xffff
        return crcsum

def watchdogtimer_ovf():
        global mystring

        #letzen beiden Bytes wegschneiden
        message = mystring[0:-4]  

        #CRC Bytes getauscht in eine Variable speichern
        crc_rx = int((mystring[-2:] + mystring[-4:-2]), 16)  

        #eigene Prüfsumme bilden
        crc_calc = crc16_x25(message)   

        #Prüfsummen vergleichen: wenn identisch
        if crc_rx == crc_calc:                                                  
                logging.info("crc OK\n")
                Database._db.insert_smlString(mystring)      
                mystring=""
                watchdog.stop()

        else:
                logging.warning("crc NOK\n\n")
                mystring=""
                watchdog.stop()

try:
        my_tty = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 9600, parity =serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0)
        logging.info(my_tty.portstr + " geoeffnet\n\n")
        my_tty.close()
        my_tty.open()


except Exception as e:
        logging.error("serieller Port konnte nicht geoeffnet werden:\n" + str(e) + "\n\n")
        exit()


try:
        my_tty.reset_input_buffer()
        my_tty.reset_output_buffer()
        watchdog = Watchdog_timer(0.1, watchdogtimer_ovf)
        watchdog.stop()
        while True:
                while my_tty.in_waiting > 0:
                        serialreturn = my_tty.read().hex()
                        mystring += serialreturn
                        watchdog.reset()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_tty.close()
        Database._db.close()
        logging.error("\nProgramm wurde manuell beendet!\n")
```

db.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import time
import datetime
import logging
from decouple import config

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

class db(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__connection = None
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
        conn = None
        try:
            # connect to the PostgreSQL server
            logging.info('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database: ' + config('DB_NAME'))
            conn = psycopg2.connect("host=" + config('DB_HOST') + " dbname=" + config('DB_NAME') + " user=" + config('DB_USER') + " password=" + config('DB_PASSWORD'))

            # create a cursor
            cur = conn.cursor()
            
            # execute a statement
            logging.info('PostgreSQL database version:')
            cur.execute('SELECT version()')

            # display the PostgreSQL database server version
            db_version = cur.fetchone()
            
            logging.info(db_version)
            
            # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
            cur.close()

            self.__connection = conn
            logging.info("connection %s ", (self.__connection))
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            logging.error("connect - error: " + error)


    def insert_smlString(self, sml_String):
        """ insert db entrie for the Smart Message Language"""
        try:
            # create a new cursor
            cur = self.__connection.cursor()

            # generate timestamp
            ts = time.time()
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            # execute the INSERT statement
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO sml_string (sml, timestamp) VALUES ( %s,%s); ",(sml_String ,timestamp))
                        
            logging.info("Insert smlString correct")

            # commit the changes to the database
            self.__connection.commit()

            # close communication with the database
            cur.close()

        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            logging.error("insert_smlString - error: " + error)   


    def close(self):
        """ Close connection from the PostgreSQL database server """
        if self.__connection is not None:
            self.__connection.close()
            logging.info('Database connection closed.')
        else:    
            logging.info('Database connection already closed!')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /home/pi

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

ENV PATH="/home/pi/.local/bin:${PATH}"

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src .

CMD ["python3", "-u", "sml.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: smlToDb
    build: .
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: always
    env_file: .env    
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    devices:
    - /dev/USBtty0:/dev/USBtty0
```

With these errors, there is often a nested for, but I don't have it.

I expected that the container is still running and not stop the python programm. So that my data comes every time in the db.

I have already made some changes, e.g. reset all variables again and again. But I am missing something. Or can it be that the logging blows up the container?

kind regards
Thomas

Comment: I removed the sml tag as the question is not related to this programming language.

Comment: Can I do something to find the error?
Or how can I narrow down the error further?